# Run server is VScode for python/django ecommerce a "type error" pops up?

Tags: python, django, web, e-commerce, project

So basically I'm trying to relearn python with this course where you make a ecommerce website using Django/Python. After adding in a Views and Urls.py the next step is to run is to hope that are three urls store, cart, checkout pop up, however in the conf.py this error pops up

```
    line 65, in _path
    raise TypeError(
    TypeError: kwargs argument must be a dict, but got str.
```

This is the line they are talking about

```
    if kwargs is not None and not isinstance(kwargs, dict):
    raise TypeError(
        f"kwargs argument must be a dict, but got 
   {kwargs.__class__.__name__}."
    )
```

i would love to know what is throwing it i tried deleting the line but that didnt work i can provide the urls and view file one of them has to be causing it i think, any help would be greatly apprecited.

Im expecting to run the server on port 8000 and be able to check if the three urls are working and will bring me up a html page, however i cant run this server due to this error, i didnt create the conf.py file so im a bit confused.

this is the views file

```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def Store(request):
   context={}
   return render(request, "Store/Store.html", context)

   def cart(request):
     context={}
     return render(request, "Store/cart.html", context)

   def checkout(request):
     context={}
     return render(request, "Store/checkout.html", context)
```

this the urls file

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns =[

                  path("", views.Store, name="Store"),
                  path("cart/", views.cart, name="cart"),
                  path("checkout/", views.checkout, name="checkout"),
   ]
```

both of these files are in a folder pathway ecommerce-store-templates-store

this is a urls.py file edited too

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path, include 

   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path("", include,"Store.urls"),
   ]
```

this  is in  a pathway ecommerce-urls.py

edit:
okay so i fixed it by doing this changing this line

```
    path("", include,"Store.urls"),
```

to

```
    path("", include("Store.urls")),
```

however now in the terminal it says permisson denied, i tried given myslef permissons to read i already had and chekced the path and try using the command prompt as admin, nothing worked any tips?

Comment: A piece of *your* code that is causing the error could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

edit: okay so i fixed it by doing this changing this line

```py
path("", include,"Store.urls"),
```

to

```py
path("", include("Store.urls")),
```